# Getting "Object doesn't support this action" in IE9 when calling sinon.spy(console,"log");

Tags: unit-testing, sinon, intern, chai

I am getting "Object doesn't support this action" in IE9 when intializing sinon.spy or stub with (console,"log");

```
spy=sinon.spy(console,"log");
custom.log("test1");
expect(spy).to.have.been.called;
spy.restore();
```

Here is the issue reported on [github/sinon](https://github.com/cjohansen/Sinon.JS/issues/386)

Is anyone faced an issue with sinonjs?

Answer (score 1):

Your first line is a spy on `console.log` and your second line is a call on `custom.log`. This looks like a simple typo—though also, there are other things to be aware of:

1. IE9 doesn’t have `console` object unless F12 Developer Tools are active
2. Console methods in IE9 aren’t real JS functions and don’t have call/apply methods, so if Sinon relies on these you can’t use it to mock console functions.

Comment: custom.log() is a method that to override native console.method. my testing is while calling custom method whether it invoke native method or not. 

If I am not opening developer tool, i am getting error as "'console' is undefined". Current error "Object doesn't support this action" is throwing after opening the developer tool